# What is the correct way to define the run time for a pub sub scheduler in cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I defined a cloud function / pub sub scheduler function like this:

```js
export const dailyStatsScheduler = functions.region('europe-west3')
    .pubsub.schedule('58 23 * * *')
    .timeZone('Europe/Berlin')
    .onRun(async (_) => {
        // Code
    });
```

Before time-savings this already ran at 1 am but after time-savings this runs at 2 am local time (Europe/Berlin) which indicates that the schedule of this function depends on the UTC time.

I would expect it to run at exactly 11:58 pm each day independently of the UTC difference.
How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Scheduler has a documented warning regarding your issue [link](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules#time_zone)

> For some time zones, daylight saving time can cause jobs to run or not
> run unexpectedly. This is because Cloud Scheduler runs on wall clock
> time. In instances where a time can occur twice (such as the case when
> clocks go backwards) and your job is scheduled at this time, your
> scheduled job might observe execution anomalies.
>
> If your job requires a very specific cadence, you might want to
> consider choosing a time zone that does not observe daylight saving
> time. Specifically, UTC is recommended for Cloud Scheduler to avoid
> the problem completely.

Therefore the solution is probably to follow the documented suggestion: use a timezone without observing daylight saving time or use UTC; or select a different service.

Comment: your answer is definitely useful although I don't think it is exactly my problem. The problem I see is that it completely ignores the time zone setting, doesn't it? On the other hand it's not very desirable to make something work which than is known to not work :-).